# How do i fix attemp to index nil with function in roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I was making a module to make my in-game UI easier to build guis but I got this error when I was testing it: attempt to index nil with 'CreateWindow'
The code:

```
local FrameLib = {}

local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

function FrameLib:CreateWindow(WindowName)
    local UICornerMain = Instance.new("UICorner")
    local UIListLayout = Instance.new("UIListLayout")
    local cvb3 = Instance.new("ScreenGui")
    local Main = Instance.new("Frame")
    local Top = Instance.new("Frame")
    local UICorner_2 = Instance.new("UICorner")
    local Bottom = Instance.new("Frame")
    local Close = Instance.new("TextButton")
    local UICorner_3 = Instance.new("UICorner")
    local Shadow = Instance.new("Folder")
    local UmbraShadow = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local PenumbraShadow = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local AmbientShadow = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UICorner_4 = Instance.new("UICorner")
    local Minimize = Instance.new("TextButton")
    local UICorner_5 = Instance.new("UICorner")
    local Shadow_2 = Instance.new("Folder")
    local UmbraShadow_2 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local PenumbraShadow_2 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local AmbientShadow_2 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local TextLabel = Instance.new("TextLabel")
    local Pattern = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local AmbientShadow1 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UIAspectRatioConstraint = Instance.new("UIAspectRatioConstraint")
    local AmbientShadow2 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UIAspectRatioConstraint_2 = Instance.new("UIAspectRatioConstraint")
    local PenumbraShadow1 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UIAspectRatioConstraint_3 = Instance.new("UIAspectRatioConstraint")
    local PenumbraShadow2 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UIAspectRatioConstraint_4 = Instance.new("UIAspectRatioConstraint")
    local UmbraShadow1 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UIAspectRatioConstraint_5 = Instance.new("UIAspectRatioConstraint")
    local UmbraShadow2 = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    local UIAspectRatioConstraint_6 = Instance.new("UIAspectRatioConstraint")
    local Stroke = Instance.new("UIStroke")
    local ButtonFrame = Instance.new("ScrollingFrame")
    local Sections = Instance.new("Frame")
    cvb3.Name = "Main"
    cvb3.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
    cvb3.ZIndexBehavior = Enum.ZIndexBehavior.Sibling

    Main.Name = "Main"
    Main.Parent = cvb3
    Main.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0, 0.5)
    Main.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(63, 63, 63)
    Main.BorderSizePixel = 0
    Main.ClipsDescendants = true
    Main.Position = UDim2.new(0.374725521, 0, 0.478996277, 0)
    Main.Size = UDim2.new(0, 421, 0, 300)

    UICornerMain.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0, 5)
    UICornerMain.Parent = Main

    Stroke.Name = "Stroke"
    Stroke.ApplyStrokeMode = Enum.ApplyStrokeMode.Contextual
    Stroke.Color = Color3.fromRGB(149,149,149)
    Stroke.LineJoinMode = Enum.LineJoinMode.Round
    Stroke.Thickness = 1
    Stroke.Enabled = true
    Stroke.Parent = Main

    Top.Name = "Top"
    Top.Parent = Main
    Top.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(44, 44, 44)
    Top.BorderSizePixel = 0
    Top.Size = UDim2.new(0, 421, 0, 32)

    UICorner_2.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0, 5)
    UICorner_2.Parent = Top

    Bottom.Name = "Bottom"
    Bottom.Parent = Top
    Bottom.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(44, 44, 44)
    Bottom.BorderSizePixel = 0
    Bottom.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0.736249983, 0)
    Bottom.Size = UDim2.new(0, 421, 0, 8)

    Close.Name = "Close"
    Close.Parent = Top
    Close.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(38, 38, 38)
    Close.BorderSizePixel = 0
    Close.Position = UDim2.new(0.914489329, 0, 0.0625, 0)
    Close.Selectable = false
    Close.Size = UDim2.new(0, 28, 0, 29)
    Close.ZIndex = 2
    Close.Selected = true
    Close.Font = Enum.Font.GothamSemibold
    Close.Text = "X"
    Close.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    Close.TextSize = 15.000
    Close.TextWrapped = true

    UICorner_3.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0, 5)
    UICorner_3.Parent = Close

    Shadow.Name = "Shadow"
    Shadow.Parent = Close

    UmbraShadow.Name = "UmbraShadow"
    UmbraShadow.Parent = Shadow
    UmbraShadow.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    UmbraShadow.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    UmbraShadow.BorderSizePixel = 0
    UmbraShadow.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 6)
    UmbraShadow.Size = UDim2.new(1, 10, 1, 10)
    UmbraShadow.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    UmbraShadow.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    UmbraShadow.ImageTransparency = 0.860
    UmbraShadow.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    UmbraShadow.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    PenumbraShadow.Name = "PenumbraShadow"
    PenumbraShadow.Parent = Shadow
    PenumbraShadow.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    PenumbraShadow.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    PenumbraShadow.BorderSizePixel = 0
    PenumbraShadow.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
    PenumbraShadow.Size = UDim2.new(1, 18, 1, 18)
    PenumbraShadow.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    PenumbraShadow.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    PenumbraShadow.ImageTransparency = 0.880
    PenumbraShadow.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    PenumbraShadow.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    AmbientShadow.Name = "AmbientShadow"
    AmbientShadow.Parent = Shadow
    AmbientShadow.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    AmbientShadow.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    AmbientShadow.BorderSizePixel = 0
    AmbientShadow.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 3)
    AmbientShadow.Size = UDim2.new(1, 5, 1, 5)
    AmbientShadow.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    AmbientShadow.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    AmbientShadow.ImageTransparency = 0.800
    AmbientShadow.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    AmbientShadow.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UICorner_4.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0, 5)
    UICorner_4.Parent = Top

    Minimize.Name = "Minimize"
    Minimize.Parent = Top
    Minimize.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(38, 38, 38)
    Minimize.BorderSizePixel = 0
    Minimize.Position = UDim2.new(0.831353962, 0, 0.0625, 0)
    Minimize.Size = UDim2.new(0, 28, 0, 29)
    Minimize.ZIndex = 2
    Minimize.Font = Enum.Font.GothamSemibold
    Minimize.Text = "-"
    Minimize.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    Minimize.TextSize = 15.000
    Minimize.TextWrapped = true

    UICorner_5.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0, 5)
    UICorner_5.Parent = Minimize

    Shadow_2.Name = "Shadow"
    Shadow_2.Parent = Minimize

    UmbraShadow_2.Name = "UmbraShadow"
    UmbraShadow_2.Parent = Shadow_2
    UmbraShadow_2.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    UmbraShadow_2.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    UmbraShadow_2.BorderSizePixel = 0
    UmbraShadow_2.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 6)
    UmbraShadow_2.Size = UDim2.new(1, 10, 1, 10)
    UmbraShadow_2.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    UmbraShadow_2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    UmbraShadow_2.ImageTransparency = 0.860
    UmbraShadow_2.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    UmbraShadow_2.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    PenumbraShadow_2.Name = "PenumbraShadow"
    PenumbraShadow_2.Parent = Shadow_2
    PenumbraShadow_2.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    PenumbraShadow_2.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    PenumbraShadow_2.BorderSizePixel = 0
    PenumbraShadow_2.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
    PenumbraShadow_2.Size = UDim2.new(1, 18, 1, 18)
    PenumbraShadow_2.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    PenumbraShadow_2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    PenumbraShadow_2.ImageTransparency = 0.880
    PenumbraShadow_2.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    PenumbraShadow_2.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    AmbientShadow_2.Name = "AmbientShadow"
    AmbientShadow_2.Parent = Shadow_2
    AmbientShadow_2.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    AmbientShadow_2.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    AmbientShadow_2.BorderSizePixel = 0
    AmbientShadow_2.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 3)
    AmbientShadow_2.Size = UDim2.new(1, 5, 1, 5)
    AmbientShadow_2.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    AmbientShadow_2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    AmbientShadow_2.ImageTransparency = 0.800
    AmbientShadow_2.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    AmbientShadow_2.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    TextLabel.Parent = Top
    TextLabel.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    TextLabel.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    TextLabel.Position = UDim2.new(0.0190023743, 0, 0.1875, 0)
    TextLabel.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 21)
    TextLabel.Font = Enum.Font.GothamSemibold
    TextLabel.Text = WindowName
    TextLabel.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    TextLabel.TextScaled = true
    TextLabel.TextSize = 14.000
    TextLabel.TextWrapped = true
    TextLabel.TextXAlignment = Enum.TextXAlignment.Left
    TextLabel.TextYAlignment = Enum.TextYAlignment.Top

    Pattern.Name = "Pattern"
    Pattern.Parent = Main
    Pattern.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    Pattern.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    Pattern.Position = UDim2.new(-0.124703087, 0, -0.146666661, 0)
    Pattern.Size = UDim2.new(0, 504, 0, 372)
    Pattern.ZIndex = 0
    Pattern.Image = "rbxassetid://2151741365"
    Pattern.ImageTransparency = 0.400
    Pattern.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Tile
    Pattern.SliceCenter = Rect.new(0, 256, 0, 256)
    Pattern.TileSize = UDim2.new(0, 250, 0, 250)

    AmbientShadow1.Name = "AmbientShadow1"
    AmbientShadow1.Parent = cvb3
    AmbientShadow1.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    AmbientShadow1.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    AmbientShadow1.BorderSizePixel = 0
    AmbientShadow1.Position = UDim2.new(0.509783506, 0, 0.481963903, 3)
    AmbientShadow1.Size = UDim2.new(0, 430, 0, 310)
    AmbientShadow1.ZIndex = 0
    AmbientShadow1.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    AmbientShadow1.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    AmbientShadow1.ImageTransparency = 0.800
    AmbientShadow1.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    AmbientShadow1.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UIAspectRatioConstraint.Parent = AmbientShadow1
    UIAspectRatioConstraint.AspectRatio = 1.386

    AmbientShadow2.Name = "AmbientShadow2"
    AmbientShadow2.Parent = cvb3
    AmbientShadow2.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    AmbientShadow2.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    AmbientShadow2.BorderSizePixel = 0
    AmbientShadow2.Position = UDim2.new(0.509783506, 0, 0.481963903, 3)
    AmbientShadow2.Size = UDim2.new(0, 430, 0, 310)
    AmbientShadow2.ZIndex = 0
    AmbientShadow2.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    AmbientShadow2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    AmbientShadow2.ImageTransparency = 0.800
    AmbientShadow2.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    AmbientShadow2.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UIAspectRatioConstraint_2.Parent = AmbientShadow2
    UIAspectRatioConstraint_2.AspectRatio = 1.386

    PenumbraShadow1.Name = "PenumbraShadow1"
    PenumbraShadow1.Parent = cvb3
    PenumbraShadow1.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    PenumbraShadow1.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    PenumbraShadow1.BorderSizePixel = 0
    PenumbraShadow1.Position = UDim2.new(0.509274423, 0, 0.48696661, 1)
    PenumbraShadow1.Size = UDim2.new(0, 431, 0, 309)
    PenumbraShadow1.ZIndex = 0
    PenumbraShadow1.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    PenumbraShadow1.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    PenumbraShadow1.ImageTransparency = 0.880
    PenumbraShadow1.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    PenumbraShadow1.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UIAspectRatioConstraint_3.Parent = PenumbraShadow1
    UIAspectRatioConstraint_3.AspectRatio = 1.398

    PenumbraShadow2.Name = "PenumbraShadow2"
    PenumbraShadow2.Parent = cvb3
    PenumbraShadow2.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    PenumbraShadow2.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    PenumbraShadow2.BorderSizePixel = 0
    PenumbraShadow2.Position = UDim2.new(0.509274423, 0, 0.48696661, 1)
    PenumbraShadow2.Size = UDim2.new(0, 431, 0, 309)
    PenumbraShadow2.ZIndex = 0
    PenumbraShadow2.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    PenumbraShadow2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    PenumbraShadow2.ImageTransparency = 0.880
    PenumbraShadow2.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    PenumbraShadow2.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UIAspectRatioConstraint_4.Parent = PenumbraShadow2
    UIAspectRatioConstraint_4.AspectRatio = 1.398

    UmbraShadow1.Name = "UmbraShadow1"
    UmbraShadow1.Parent = cvb3
    UmbraShadow1.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    UmbraShadow1.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    UmbraShadow1.BorderSizePixel = 0
    UmbraShadow1.Position = UDim2.new(0.509783506, 0, 0.478506416, 6)
    UmbraShadow1.Size = UDim2.new(0, 430, 0, 308)
    UmbraShadow1.ZIndex = 0
    UmbraShadow1.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    UmbraShadow1.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    UmbraShadow1.ImageTransparency = 0.860
    UmbraShadow1.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    UmbraShadow1.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UIAspectRatioConstraint_5.Parent = UmbraShadow1
    UIAspectRatioConstraint_5.AspectRatio = 1.395

    UmbraShadow2.Name = "UmbraShadow2"
    UmbraShadow2.Parent = cvb3
    UmbraShadow2.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    UmbraShadow2.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    UmbraShadow2.BorderSizePixel = 0
    UmbraShadow2.Position = UDim2.new(0.509783506, 0, 0.478506416, 6)
    UmbraShadow2.Size = UDim2.new(0, 430, 0, 308)
    UmbraShadow2.ZIndex = 0
    UmbraShadow2.Image = "rbxassetid://1316045217"
    UmbraShadow2.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    UmbraShadow2.ImageTransparency = 0.860
    UmbraShadow2.ScaleType = Enum.ScaleType.Slice
    UmbraShadow2.SliceCenter = Rect.new(10, 10, 118, 118)

    UIAspectRatioConstraint_6.Parent = UmbraShadow2
    UIAspectRatioConstraint_6.AspectRatio = 1.395

    ButtonFrame.Name = "ButtonFrame"
    ButtonFrame.Parent = Main
    ButtonFrame.Active = true
    ButtonFrame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(44, 44, 44)
    ButtonFrame.BorderSizePixel = 0
    ButtonFrame.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0.106666669, 0)
    ButtonFrame.Size = UDim2.new(0, 88, 0, 268)
    ButtonFrame.ScrollBarThickness = 0

    UIListLayout.HorizontalAlignment = Enum.HorizontalAlignment.Left
    UIListLayout.Parent = ButtonFrame

    AmbientShadow.Parent = Main
    AmbientShadow1.Parent = Main
    AmbientShadow2.Parent = Main
    PenumbraShadow.Parent = Main
    PenumbraShadow1.Parent = Main
    PenumbraShadow2.Parent = Main
    UmbraShadow.Parent = Main
    UmbraShadow1.Parent = Main
    UmbraShadow2.Parent = Main

    AmbientShadow.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    AmbientShadow1.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    AmbientShadow2.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    PenumbraShadow.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    PenumbraShadow1.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    PenumbraShadow2.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    UmbraShadow.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    UmbraShadow1.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)
    UmbraShadow2.Position = UDim2.new(0.498, 0,0.506, 3)

    AmbientShadow.ZIndex = -1
    AmbientShadow1.ZIndex = -1
    AmbientShadow2.ZIndex = -1
    PenumbraShadow.ZIndex = -1
    PenumbraShadow1.ZIndex = -1
    PenumbraShadow2.ZIndex = -1
    UmbraShadow.ZIndex = -1
    UmbraShadow1.ZIndex = -1
    UmbraShadow2.ZIndex = -1

    Sections.Name = "Sections"
    Sections.Parent = Main
    Sections.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sections.BackgroundTransparency = 1.000
    Sections.Position = UDim2.new(0.211401418, 0, 0.109999999, 0)
    Sections.Size = UDim2.new(0, 332, 0, 267)

    local PatStroke = Instance.new("UIStroke")
    local PatCorner = Instance.new("UICorner")
    PatCorner.Parent = Pattern
    PatCorner.CornerRadius = UDim.new(0,5)
    PatStroke.Parent = Pattern
    PatStroke.Color = Color3.fromRGB(149, 149, 149)
    PatStroke.LineJoinMode = Enum.LineJoinMode.Round
    Pattern.ZIndex = 0
    Pattern.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(63, 63, 63)
    Pattern.BackgroundTransparency = 0
end
```

I was searching about this error with a function but I couldn't find any so I'm trying if here I can get any help about this error because I have been working very hard on this to make my GUI easier to build but well it's now struggling me to find any solutions.

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you've shared. What code is calling `FrameLib:CreateWindow("something")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not in the provided code.

It must be something where you do.

`someVariable["CreateWindow"]`, `someVariable.CreateWindow` or `someVariable:CreateWindow()` where `someVariable` is a nil value. Indexing nil values is not allowed.

You failed to refer that variable to your `FrameLib` table. Maybe just a typo? Lua errors typically come with a stack trace that provides you with information about which line of which file cause the error together with the sequence of function calls that lead to that error.

If you don't know the three possible indexing operations in Lua and hence what to look for in this case you probably should revisit the basics of Lua befor doing any further Roblox development.